# Yesod Quick Start Fails at Stack Build

Tags: yesod

I attempted to do the yesod quick start guide last night and on step 4 running `stack build` yields the errror

`Error parsing targets: The specified targets matched no packages.
Perhaps you need to run 'stack init'?`

running `stack init` yields a big large error as well

Is there any resolution for this?

Edit: Adding error from the `stack init` command

```
Looking for .cabal or package.yaml files to use to init the project.
Using cabal packages:
- ./

Selecting the best among 15 snapshots...

* Partially matches lts-13.21
    aeson version 1.4.2.0 found
        - edb-yesod requires >=0.6 && <1.4
    classy-prelude version 1.5.0 found
        - edb-yesod requires ==1.4.*
    classy-prelude-conduit version 1.5.0 found
        - edb-yesod requires ==1.4.*
    classy-prelude-yesod version 1.5.0 found
        - edb-yesod requires ==1.4.*
    persistent version 2.9.2 found
        - edb-yesod requires ==2.8.*
    persistent-sqlite version 2.9.3 found
        - edb-yesod requires ==2.8.*
    yaml version 0.11.0.0 found
        - edb-yesod requires ==0.8.*
    Using package flags:
        - edb-yesod: dev = False, library-only = False

Downloaded nightly-2019-05-18 build plan.    
Unable to load cabal files for snapshot

----
Deleting cached snapshot file: /home/decapo/.stack/build-plan/nightly-2019-05-18.yaml
Recommendation: try running again. If this fails again, open an upstream issue at:
https://github.com/fpco/stackage-nightly/issues/new
----

Unable to parse cabal file for co-log-0.3.0.0@sha256:0eb5cf2598c3673f39a8e967a6a4f5043f4d1f1fcb50a844653c34fcf0cb068a,4508

- 0:0: Unsupported cabal-version. See https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4899.
```

## Edit 2

Adding output from stack new yesod-sqlite template

```
» stack new my-project-du yesod-sqlite
Downloading template "yesod-sqlite" to create project "my-project-du" in my-project-du/ ...
Looking for .cabal or package.yaml files to use to init the project.
Using cabal packages:
- my-project-du/

Selecting the best among 15 snapshots...

* Partially matches lts-13.21
    aeson version 1.4.2.0 found
        - my-project-du requires >=0.6 && <1.4
    classy-prelude version 1.5.0 found
        - my-project-du requires ==1.4.*
    classy-prelude-conduit version 1.5.0 found
        - my-project-du requires ==1.4.*
    classy-prelude-yesod version 1.5.0 found
        - my-project-du requires ==1.4.*
    persistent version 2.9.2 found
        - my-project-du requires ==2.8.*
    persistent-sqlite version 2.9.3 found
        - my-project-du requires ==2.8.*
    yaml version 0.11.0.0 found
        - my-project-du requires ==0.8.*
    Using package flags:
        - my-project-du: dev = False, library-only = False

Unable to load cabal files for snapshot

----
Deleting cached snapshot file: /home/decapo/.stack/build-plan/nightly-2019-05-18.yaml
Recommendation: try running again. If this fails again, open an upstream issue at:
https://github.com/fpco/stackage-nightly/issues/new
----

Unable to parse cabal file for co-log-0.3.0.0@sha256:0eb5cf2598c3673f39a8e967a6a4f5043f4d1f1fcb50a844653c34fcf0cb068a,4508

- 0:0: Unsupported cabal-version. See https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4899.
```

Looks like something similar to the stack init command.  For details on my system I'm running ubuntu mate 18.04 64-bit.

Comment: Is there any stack.yaml file? Did you run the command from the generated directory? What error messages does stack init produce?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman There is not a stack.yaml file but there is a package.yaml file.  I ran the command from another directory and then cd into the project directory.  I've edited my question to show the error from the ```stack init``` command.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman I attempted to create a new project and put the output of that in my second edit.

Comment: I think the problem is that the instructions are out of date, I've just pushed a commit to fix them. Can you try instead running `stack new my-project yesodweb/sqlite`?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Unfortunately when I run the command above stack tells me that template does not exist.  Running stack templates shows the yesod templates with the old yesod-{extra} where extra is minimal, mysql, sqlite, etc... my stack version is ```Version 1.7.1, Git revision 681c800873816c022739ca7ed14755e85a579565 (5807 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.28.2```

Comment: Oh, that's easy, you need to upgrade. Try running stack upgrade

Comment: That got It going!  Thank you for your help and also thank you for creating these awesome libraries in haskell.

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck